# how to find rows with duplicate values with doctrine?

Tags: mysql, doctrine

Is there a smart way with Doctrine to find all rows that have the same value in a specific column?

I can of course take the value of each line and start a search in the table, or save it in an array, but I hope there is a better solution.

Comment: Most used MySQL query to find duplicates is    `SELECT [column] FROM [table] GROUP BY [column] HAVING COUNT(*) > 1`

Comment: ok that works for me too, thx